# How to edit WordPress comment before the page is rendered?

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, you can do the following to edit the content of an article before the page is loaded:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'edit_content');
function edit_content($content) {
    // edit $content
    return $content;
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing but for comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a filter to the `comment_text` hook, similar to how you do it with `the_content` hook. This hook lets you change the comment text that is displayed using `comment_text()` in your template.

**For example:**

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'edit_comment_text', 99);
function edit_comment_text( $comment_text, $commentObject, $args ) {
    // edit the text....
    return $comment_text;
}
```

Note that you might need to set the priority in `add_filter` to a high number so that it runs after WP's own filters first - I used `99` above.

You can see in the [WP Developer Code Reference for `comment_text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_text/) that the 3 parameters the filter gets are:

- `$comment_text` (string) - Text of the current comment.
- `$commentObject` (WP_Comment|null) - The comment object. Null if not found.
- `$args` (array) - An array of arguments.